# Get data asynchronously and then then process data serially with RxJava

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a function that creates an observable that is responsible for fetching some data. This function is called multiple times so that there are N threads in the background that fetch data. Once the data have been fetched, I have to process them serially. Each round of processing should begin when a notification arrives and all the data are processed one by one (we don't care about the order or if there are still X background threads that still fetch data while we process the data we currently have).

Currently I have a solution implemented but it's not entirely correct as the currentSubject only returns the first value.

Example code here:

```
package Test;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    var t = new Test();

    var<String> currentSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    var n = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      Observable.zip(
              currentSubject,
              t.getData(String.valueOf(i), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5)),
              (s1, s2) -> s1 + " for " + s2)
          .first("Default")
          .doOnEvent(
              (s, e) -> {
                System.out.println("Processing result: " + s);
              })
          .subscribe();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      Thread.sleep(i * 2000);
      currentSubject.onNext("A notification: "+i);
    }
    System.out.println("End");
  }

  public Observable<String> getData(String s, int sec) {
    return Observable.just(s)
        .delay(sec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .doOnNext(
            dt -> {
              System.out.println("Got data: " + dt);
            })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and "currentSubject" only returns the first value? I'm creating multiple Observables each time, can this cause a problem e.g. having multiple Observables in memory while they should have been disposed? And finally how can I use the "currentSubject" multiple times without a problem?

Comment: I'd like to help but I'm finding the explanation a bit confusing. Do you mean `getData()` is invoked multiple times (at some unpredictable the time), and the results of each invocation should be handled serially in whatever order they come?

Comment: Yeah that's right. You can think of getData as a background thread that fetches data and then the main thread processes the data one by one, when a notification arrives e.g. Fetch Data 1, Fetch Data 2, Process Data 1, Fetch Data 3, Notification that 1 is done, Process Data 2, Notification that 2 is done, Process Data 3, Notification that 3 is done and finish. I managed to implement a solution using 2 PublishSubject object that are zipped and wait for notifications. Curious if there is an other solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by creating two PublishSubjects. One that is responsible for fetching the data in a background thread and one that is called when a notification arrives. Using the "zip"/"zipWith" operator the data are processed only when a notification arrives, one by one.

Sample code:

```
package Test;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  var t = new Test();
  var<String> fetchDataSubject = PublishSubject.create();
  var<String> notificationSubject = PublishSubject.create();

  fetchDataSubject
      .flatMap(
          (e) -> {
            return t.getData(String.valueOf(e), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 
                   4));
        })
      .zipWith(notificationSubject, (s1, s2) -> s1 + " for " + s2)
      .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
      .subscribe(
          (s) -> {
            System.out.println(
                "Result: " + s + ", running on thread: " + 
                  Thread.currentThread().getName());
          },
          (e) -> {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
          });

  // Start fetching all data in background jobs
  var n = 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fetchDataSubject.onNext(String.valueOf(i));
  }
  
  // Send notifications
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    notificationSubject.onNext(" \"Notification " + i + "\"");

    // Emulate notification arriving after the processing
    Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 10) * 1000);
  }

  Thread.sleep(40000);
}

public Observable<String> getData(String s, int sec) {

  // Wait some time to fetch data on another thread
  return Observable.just(s)
      .delay(sec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .doOnNext(
          dt -> {
            System.out.println(
                "Got data: "
                    + dt
                    + " after waiting: "
                    + sec
                    + "s, on  thread "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          })
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
  }
}
```